# Find same DOM-element with JSoup and JS?

Tags: java, javascript, dom, jsoup

Is there some unique, inherent attribute of a DOM element that makes it possible to select the same element with both JSoup and Javascript?

I currently both render a page with webEngine and extract the DOM-tree using JSoup. I want to associate the offset values from an element in the rendered page, which I get using executeScript on the webEngine, with information that I collect using JSoup. But currently I don't know how to select the same DOM-element with Javascript and JSoup.

I'm thinking of maybe using the fact the each element has a unique parent vector if you include the sibling index, but perhaps there is a faster way?

Comment: Do you really need JSoup for this? Could you do all the required DOM transformations within `WebEngine`?

Comment: Good point @AndreyChaschev, maybe I don't. I'll give that a try. Thanks for helping out (again ;)!

Comment: You're welcome. See you back at SO!